# Retaining dropdown selection on postback creates empty options

Tags: php

I want to retain the users dropdown selection after the form has been submitted, however, since I added the code to do this it has created empty options in my dropdown list (even before anything is submitted). What is happening and how can I rectify it? Any help is very much appreciated.

```
$sals = array('Mr','Mrs','Miss','Dr');

<label>Salutation: </label>
<select name='mysal'> 

<?php
foreach ($sals as $sal) {
echo "<option value='$sal'"; 
if($sal == @$sal_conf) echo 'SELECTED'; 
echo ">".$sal."<option />";                     
}
?>
```

If submit button (omitted here) is pressed:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$sal_conf = $_POST['mysal'];
}
```

Opening the drop down list look like this

> Mr
>
> Mrs
>
> Miss
>
> Dr

There is an empty selection after each option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try.

```
<?php
foreach ($sals as $sal) {
  $selected = ($sal == $sal_conf) ? ' SELECTED' : ''; 
  echo '<option value="'.$sal.'"'.$selected.'>'.$sal.'</option>';                     
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeeeessss. Thank you very much, it works. The empty selection spaces have gone and the previous selection is retained. You are fantastic

Comment: oops i forgot about accepting the answer, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed your

```
   <option></option>
```

i find it cleaner to use curly braces {} when I have inline variables instead of closing the string when am using double quotes.

```
    foreach($sals as $sal){
     echo "<option value={$sal}";
     if($sal == @$sal_conf) {echo  "SELECTED "; }
    echo " >{$sal}<option />";  
    }
```

Comment: many thanks for your help, but I pasted your code into mine and the spaces in the options were still there and it didnt retain the previous selection. Plus I did close the option tag, I'm not sure if you've missed it my first post.